# Twig replace part of string with chosen character

Tags: twig

I want to replace part of string characters with asterisks in Twig.

For example:

```
SomePartlyVisibleStringHere
```

I want to change every letter after 4th in this string with asterisks, to have result like that:

```
Some*********************
```

Is it possible to do without defining new Twig helper?

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if one solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) (a function in Twig) and call it whenever you want to do this.

```
{% macro redact(topSecret) %}
    {% set length = topSecret|length - 4 %}
    {{ topSecret|slice(0, 3) }}{% for i in 0..length %}*{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{# You have to import from _self if the macro is declared in the same file. #}
{% import _self as sharpie %}

{{ sharpie.redact('Top secret information') }}
{# => Top******************* #}
```

Example: https://twigfiddle.com/aobt8s

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
{% set string = 'SomePartlyVisibleStringHere' %}
{% set starCount = string|length - 4 %}
{{ string[:4] }}{% for i in 1..starCount %}*{% endfor %}
```

If you have to do it more than once I would suggest [making a custom filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters), then you can just do:

```
{% set string = 'SomePartlyVisibleStringHere' %}
{{ string|customFilterName }}
```